# Accessing a variable from another script C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Can you tell me how to access a variable of a script from another script ? I have even read everything in unity website but I still can’t do it. I know how to access another object but not another variable.

This is the situation :
I’m in script **B** and I want to access the variable `X` from script **A**. The variable `X` is `boolean`.
Can you help me ?

Btw i need to update `X`’s value costantly in script **B** , how do I do that ? Access it in `Update` function
If you could give me and example with these letters would be great !

Thank you

Comment: Could you add some example code of your two scripts? Would help in providing you a solution.

Answer (score 18):

You first need to get the script component of the variable, and if they're in different game objects, you'll need to pass the Game Object as a reference in the inspector.

For example, I have `scriptA.cs` in `GameObject A` and `scriptB.cs` in `GameObject B`:

**scriptA.cs**

```
// make sure its type is public so you can access it later on
public bool X = false;
```

**scriptB.cs**

```
public GameObject a; // you will need this if scriptB is in another GameObject
                     // if not, you can omit this
                     // you'll realize in the inspector a field GameObject will appear
                     // assign it just by dragging the game object there
public scriptA script; // this will be the container of the script

void Start(){
    // first you need to get the script component from game object A
    // getComponent can get any components, rigidbody, collider, etc from a game object
    // giving it <scriptA> meaning you want to get a component with type scriptA
    // note that if your script is not from another game object, you don't need "a."
    // script = a.gameObject.getComponent<scriptA>(); <-- this is a bit wrong, thanks to user2320445 for spotting that
    // don't need .gameObject because a itself is already a gameObject
    script = a.getComponent<scriptA>();
}

void Update(){
    // and you can access the variable like this
    // even modifying it works
    script.X = true;
}
```

Comment: Should the way to acces `X` be with `script.X = true;` rather than `scriptA.X = true;` ? You can't access `X` that way if it is not `static`

Comment: @GrayCygnus whoops u spotted my mistake. Thanks, I have fixed it.

Comment: If you reference the GameObject `a`  anyway you could also simply reference the wanted component directly without having to call `GetComponent`

Answer (score 1):

just for completing the first answer

there is no need for

```c#
a.gameObject.getComponent<scriptA>();
```

`a` is already a `GameObject` so this will do

```c#
a.getComponent<scriptA>();
```

and if the variable you are trying to access is in children of the `GameObject` you should use

```c#
a.GetComponentInChildren<scriptA>();
```

and if you need a variable of it or method you can access it like this

```c#
a.GetComponentInChildren<scriptA>().nameofyourvar;
a.GetComponentInChildren<scriptA>().nameofyourmethod(Methodparams);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use static here.

here is the example:

**ScriptA.cs**

```
Class ScriptA : MonoBehaviour{
 public static bool X = false;
}
```

**ScriptB.cs**

```
Class ScriptB : MonoBehaviour{
 void Update() {
   bool AccesingX = ScriptA.X;
   // or you can do this also 
   ScriptA.X = true;
 }
}
```

> OR

**ScriptA.cs**

```
Class ScriptA : MonoBehaviour{

//you are actually creating instance of this class to access variable.
 public static ScriptA instance;

 void Awake(){

     // give reference to created object.
     instance = this;

 }

 // by this way you can access non-static members also.
 public bool X = false;


}
```

**ScriptB.cs**

```
Class ScriptB : MonoBehaviour{
 void Update() {
   bool AccesingX = ScriptA.instance.X;
   // or you can do this also 
   ScriptA.instance.X = true;
 }
}
```

for more detail, you can refer singleton class.