# Unity access boolean from script to use in other script Google Cardboard

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

In my menu scene, I have a boolean button that triggers the function `LoadStereo()`, which allows either `VRModeEnabled` or `!VRModeEnabled`.

```
GvrViewer MonoOrStereo = new GvrViewer(); 

void Awake() { 
    bool stereo = MonoOrStereo.VRModeEnabled; 
} 

public void LoadStereo(bool stereo) { 
    Debug.Log (stereo); 
}
```

This seems to be logging true and false so my two buttons are giving me the right values when clicked.

But I'm having trouble sending this value to the Loaded scene. In the start function of the Loaded scene, I have

```
void Start() { 
     GameObject MonoOrStereo = GameObject.Find("MonoOrStereo"); 
     Menu menu = MonoOrStereo.GetComponent<Menu>(); 
}
```

but I cant access the boolean `menu.stereo`, only `menu.LoadStereo()`. How can I turn this into a boolean I can use in my code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing a variable from another script C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930919/accessing-a-variable-from-another-script-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the `stereo` variable from the `Menu` script because `stereo` is declared in a function. Declare it outside a function then initialize it in the `Awake()` function. You must also make it `public` in order to be able to access it.

```
public GvrViewer MonoOrStereo = new GvrViewer(); 
public bool stereo;

void Awake() { 
    stereo = MonoOrStereo.VRModeEnabled; 
} 

public void LoadStereo(bool stereo) { 
    Debug.Log (stereo); 
}
```