# Score won't reset

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When my player dies the score continues on and does not reset, it continues the score from the previous session. I would like to reset back to 0 once the player dies, I've added the two scripts

Score script:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ScoreScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public static int scoreValue = 0;
    Text score;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        score = GetComponent<Text>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        score.text = " " + scoreValue;
    }
}
```

Player Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

    public float jumpForce = 10f;

    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public SpriteRenderer sr;

    public string currentColor;

    public Color colorCyan;
    public Color colorYellow;
    public Color colorMagenta;
    public Color colorPink;

    void Start ()
    {
        SetRandomColor();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.tag == "ColorChanger")
        {
            ScoreScript.scoreValue += 1;
            SetRandomColor();
            Destroy(col.gameObject);
            return;
        }

        if (col.tag != currentColor)
        {
            Debug.Log("GAME OVER!");
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
        }
    }

    void SetRandomColor ()
    {
        int index = Random.Range(0, 4);

        switch (index)
        {
            case 0:
                currentColor = "Cyan";
                sr.color = colorCyan;
                break;
            case 1:
                currentColor = "Yellow";
                sr.color = colorYellow;
                break;
            case 2:
                currentColor = "Magenta";
                sr.color = colorMagenta;
                break;
            case 3:
                currentColor = "Pink";
                sr.color = colorPink;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried making the `scoreValue` non-static?

Comment: How would I go about making it non-static. Can't find any tutorials, sorry :S

Comment: @ROOT : See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930919/accessing-a-variable-from-another-script-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `scoreValue` is a static variable, meaning it's maintained globally rather than per-instantiation of the `ScoreScript` behavior.

First off, I would change `scoreValue` to not be static. Then, just like you have for components such as `RigidBody2D`, I would add a public reference to the `ScoreScript` in your Player, drag that object to that field in the Unity editor, and then whenever making changes to `scoreValue`, use your new local reference to the `ScoreScript`. (So, `scoreScript` rather than `ScoreScript`).

Since like all behaviours, the `ScoreScript` will be reconstructed when the scene resets, this means it will then start at 0. It's not restarting right now because loading a new scene just remakes objects, it doesn't restart the entire scripting environment along with global static variables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be modifying the `static` variable inside of your `ScoreScript` whenever the conditions for death are validated in your `Player` component.

Judging by the source, it looks like the line:

`if (col.tag != currentColor)`

denotes the end of a game. If this is the case, you'll want to reference `ScoreScript.score` after the `if` statement and set the value of this static variable to 0 to reset the score upon death.

Comment: like this ?  `if 
            (col.tag != currentColor)
  {
            *ScoreScript.scoreValue = 0;*
            Debug.Log("GAME OVER!");
   SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
  }`