# How can I create a coin GUI label in a main menu that can be increased by collecting more coins in a level?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I am working on a game in Unity 2018.2.5f1. I have it setup where in a level you can collect coins placed around the level. I also have GUI label setup to count the coins you have collected. Then, in my main menu I have setup, There is another GUI label that is going to show how many coins you have collected throughout you playing. The problem is, I have been searching for a long time on how I can take the Level coin counter GUI label and add it to the main menu Coin counter GUI label. Below is the C# code for this (It really is not a lot of code).

```
public GUIStyle COINStyle; 

private void OnGUI()
{
    GUI.Label(new Rect(10, 10, 100, 20), "Coins : " + coins, COINStyle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the start of the game, set a prior-to-level coin counter:

```
int alreadyGotCoins = 0;
```

Then, at the end of each level success, update it with how many coins were collected before resetting the level coin counter:

```
alreadyGotCoins = alreadyGotCoins + coins;
coins = 0;
```

And then, on the main menu UI display the sum of the current level + prior coin counts:

```
GUI.Label(new Rect(...), "Total coins : " + (coins + alreadyGotCoins), mainMenuCoinStyle);
```

Comment: What exactly should I do to "update" it. I don't what I am supposed to update or how I am supposed to update it.

Comment: You haven't shared enough of your code for me to give you an exact line to put in your code. `alreadyGotCoins = alreadyGotCoins + coins;` does the update to `alreadyGotCoins`. You need to put in variables/references that make sense for your code. It might look more like `gameManager.alreadyGotCoins = gameManager.alreadyGotCoins + gameManager.levelCoins`. I have no idea what your code looks like outside of the 3 lines in your question, but this answer is meant to broadly tell you how to go about solving your question regardless of your exact code structure.

Comment: @Sam If you need help getting variables from other scripts, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930919/accessing-a-variable-from-another-script-c-sharp) question.

Answer (score 0):

the way i have implemented this in the past was with tags. i would have a global variable class that stores all my variables, and use `DontDestroyOnLoad(this)` in its `Awake()` method. then i tag it "Global"

then i can do something like:

```
GlobalVariables gvar =GameObject.FindObjectWithTag("Global").GetComponent<GlobalVariables>();
```

in your menu class, and then use it to grab your stuff, like:

```
   int newcoins = gvar.coinscollectedlastlevel;
   gvar.coinscollectedlastlevel=0;
   coins= coins + newcoins;
```