# Unable to get value of public variable into another script in Unity3D c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a `public Color winColor` var in my `gameController.cs` script. I am setting its value in the `Start()`. Now I want to get its value in another script `check.cs`.

Now I since it is public I have used `GameObject.Find("gameController").GetComponent<gamePlay>().winColor;`
The issue here is that it is displaying a different value.
This is my code in `tile.cs`

```
private Color winingColor;

    void Start () 
    {
        winingColor = GameObject.Find("gameController").GetComponent<gamePlay>().winColor;
        Debug.Log(winingColor);
    }

    void Update () 
    {
        Vector2 mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

        bool overSprite = this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.Contains(mousePosition);

        if (overSprite)
        {
            if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
            {

                if (this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color == winingColor)
                {
                    float x = this.gameObject.transform.position.x;
                    this.gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(x, 3.5f, 0.0f);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`gameController.cs`Code

```
public GameObject ball;
    public List<GameObject> tiles;

    private Color [] colors = { new Color(0,1,0,1), new Color(1,0,0,1), new Color(1,1,1,1), new Color(0,0,1,1),  new Color(1,1,0,1), new Color(0, 0, 0, 1)};

    public Color winColor;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        winColor = colors[1];
        Debug.Log("con wincolor:" + winColor);
        ball.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = colors[1];
        tiles[0].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = colors[0];
        tiles[1].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = colors[1];
        tiles[2].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = colors[3];
        tiles[3].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = colors[4];

    }
```

The value of `winColor` in `gameController.cs` is `RGBA(1.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000)`
But in `tile.cs` I am getting `RGBA(0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000)`

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you post your gameController code?

Comment: Added the `gameController` code

Comment: Is the class in `gameController.cs` called gameController or gamePlay?
The function `getComponent` in the line `GameObject.Find("gameController").GetComponent<gamePlay>().winColor` is trying to get a class called `gamePlay`, you should check that the type parameter in the `getComponent` call corresponds to the class in the `gameController.cs` file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing a variable from another script C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930919/accessing-a-variable-from-another-script-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start() of different game objects is happening in the order you don't expect.
If Tile.cs Start() happens first, winColor won't be set yet.

Move this line into Awake()

```
winColor = colors[1];
```

Another way you could solve this, if winColor isn't supposed to change, is you could change winColor to a Property getter, and remove the `winColor = colors[1];` line.

```
public Color winColor { get { return colors[1];}}
```

Comment: No winColor will change this is just the start of my project. But yes I forgot to use Awake(). It works.

Answer (score 0):

In my experiment it is working, are you sure you are not changing the color somewhere on the code?

Test2:

```
public class test2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Color winColor;
    private Color[] colors = { new Color(0, 1, 0, 1), new Color(1, 0, 0, 1), new Color(1, 1, 1, 1), new Color(0, 0, 1, 1), new Color(1, 1, 0, 1), new Color(0, 0, 0, 1) };

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        winColor = colors[1];
        Debug.Log("con wincolor:" + winColor);
    }

}
```

Test1:

```
public class test1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Color winingColor;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        winingColor = GameObject.Find("test").GetComponent<test2>().winColor;
        Debug.Log("test1:" + winingColor);
    }    
}
```

Also in my opinion it woul be better to use [Getters/Setters](https://www.dotnetperls.com/property) to access public propierties, they give you better flexibility:

```
public class test2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Color[] colors = { new Color(0, 1, 0, 1), new Color(1, 0, 0, 1), new Color(1, 1, 1, 1), new Color(0, 0, 1, 1), new Color(1, 1, 0, 1), new Color(0, 0, 0, 1) };

    public Color winColor
    {
        get; set;
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        winColor = colors[1];
        Debug.Log("con wincolor:" + winColor);
    }

}
```