# Cannot reference a script on an array of gameobjects generated in another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want an array of game objects, each game object has a simple script to move it. I want a controlling script to be able to trigger the remote script by referencing the array coordinates / game object at that point.

I am missing something basic in referencing a "global" variable - so apologies in advance. I have spent several hours now reading and trying things out. 
Example questions like here [Accessing a variable from another script C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930919/accessing-a-variable-from-another-script-c-sharp)
or
https://answers.unity.com/questions/42843/referencing-non-static-variables-from-another-scri.html

I believe the array should be static as there is only one set of data, however I don't care if it isnt

CreateGrid.cs

```
public class CreateGrid : MonoBehaviour
{

public static GameObject[,] gridArray = new GameObject[5, 5];
public GameObject gridSpace;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    GenerateGrid();
}

void GenerateGrid()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        for (int z = 0; z < 5; z++)
        {
            gridArray[x, z] = Instantiate(gridSpace, new Vector3(x, 0, z), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        }
    }

    // test grid works
    // gridArray[2, 2].transform.Translate(0.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f);
}
```

}

test code

```
public class Pulse : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

     for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
        {
        CreateGrid.gridArray[x, 3].GetComponent<MoveObject>().StartBounce(5.0f);
        }
    }
}
```

The grid of objects works.
However the test code errors with Object reference not set to an instance of an object from the line 
    CreateGrid.gridArray[x, 3].GetComponent().StartBounce(5.0f);

specifically CreateGrid.gridArray

Given that I seem to be really struggling with a concept, please explain clearly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you don't [clearly define otherwise](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html), you don't know when the `Start` method of two MonoBehaviours will run.

In your case, the `Pulse`'s Start method is called **before** `CreateGrid`'s.

To fix your problem, I advise you to call `CreateGrid`'s `Generate` method inside the `Awake` method of the class.

I often use this method to initialize members of the class not relying on other classes instances and use the `Start` method to initialize members needing other instances to be self-initialized.

Comment: Of all the things I looked at, undefined start order never appeared. Using the script execution order from your link has worked. Will try the awake approach shortly