# Unity how do I make my gun stop shooting when the Player is moving?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]I am making a gun shooting script, but I do not know how to disable shooting when the player is running. Can someone help me with that?

```
void Shoot()
{
    MuzzleFlash.Play();


    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(cam.transform.position, cam.transform.forward, out hit, Range))
    {
        Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);

        EnemyHealth enemy = hit.transform.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>();
        if (enemy != null)
        {
            enemy.TakeDamage(Damage);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the movement section of my character controller script:

```
void Movement()
{
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * WalkSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * WalkSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        WalkSpeed = RunSpeed;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        WalkSpeed = DefaultSpeed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set variables in other scripts like this:

```
[Serialize Field]
private GameObject objectWithYourScriptYouNeed; 
private ClassOfScriptYouNeed pS; 


void Start()
{     
    pS = objectWithYourScript.GetComponent<ClassOfScriptYouNeed>();    
    pS.varName = 12345;
}
```

---

So, in your shoot script:

```
Public Bool isMoving;

void Shoot()
{
    //I'm assuming you also dont want muzzleflash to play.
    if (isMoving != true)
    {
        MuzzleFlash.Play();    

        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(cam.transform.position, cam.transform.forward, out hit, Range))
        {

            Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);

            EnemyHealth enemy = hit.transform.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>();
            if (enemy != null)
            {
                enemy.TakeDamage(Damage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your movement Script:

```
//put your shooting scripts name below.
private ShootScript shootScript; 

void start()
{    

    shootScript = GetComponent<ShootScript>();

}

void Movement()
{
    shootScript.isMoving = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") != 0f 
                           || Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") != 0f ; 

    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") 
                        * WalkSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") 
                        * WalkSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    // GetKey is true on every frame that shift is held down, and false when it isn't
    // GetKeyDown is only true on the first frame in a row that shift is held down    
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        WalkSpeed = RunSpeed;
    }
    else 
    {
        WalkSpeed = DefaultSpeed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay that helps a bit but I still dont know how to make the if statement for it.

Comment: it just gives me an error with private parentScript = pS;

Comment: i am uploading a screenshot of what happens

Comment: Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration                  Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
Invalid expression term ';'

Comment: Did you change code? You have an error from mine. It is pC = <GetComponent>(PlayerController);

Comment: private PlayerController = pC;          //      pC = <GetComponent>(PlayerController);

Comment: My bad I believe it is just Private PlayerController pC; .. there is no equals sign. Very hard to do without Unity on hand.

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean also this is the error Invalid expression term '<'

Comment: I would suggest looking up some videos on how to reference other scripts variables. I dont want this to get too long and be an annoyance to people. There is plenty of videos, once you have that the other logic should work out if you understand it. Sorry for the inconvenience it is just too hard for me to error check at the moment

Comment: If you have not found anything yet, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930919/accessing-a-variable-from-another-script-c-sharp This is very helpful. This allows you to grab a script from another game object.

Comment: @EthanK-B I fixed some of the syntax errors in this question. You never mention the names of your scripts' classes so I can't put the exact terms in. Hopefully they make sense.

Comment: Thank you again Ruzihm for your awesome work! Hope this solves your question now Ethan.

Comment: @EthanK-B I changed the answer to avoid the need for setting `isMoving` back to `false` manually.

Answer (score 2):

Make a boolean `isMoving` and when they're moving set it to true and false when they stop.  Then in your `void Shoot` make an if statement for the moving bool and only fire when it's false.

Comment: The only problem is that the character controller script that controls movement is on the parent object while the shooting script is attached to child object.